# pointerdown event unexpected behaviour in touch devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

- i'm trying to create a long press function that will change touched element background after 1 second and when there's one element background is chaned the other elements will be able to change background by just click but just when there's an active element - everything is well for now but there's unexpected behavior that is happend on touch devices when i scroll down to see other elements and put the touch pointer on the element for less than 1 second and take my hand up the function will work and will be appied to touched element like the pointer is still in there's although that i removed my hand over of this element i don't know where's the problem exactly i tried something like `touch-action: none` but it's stopping the touch over those elements and i want the touch to work normally to be able to scroll down when move the pointer over those elements
- also when select some elements and touch active element to scroll down for select other elements it's remove the class from touched element after a while
- **Here's a simple example of my code**

```js
var n = document.getElementsByClassName("items"),
            container = document.getElementsByClassName("items")[0];

        function longPress(el, timeout, callback) {
            var timer;
            el.addEventListener("pointerdown", function(e) {
                this.style.touchAction = "none"
                if (e.buttons === 1) {
                    timer = setTimeout(function() {
                        callback(e, el)
                    }, timeout);
                }
            })
            el.addEventListener("pointerup", function(e) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                //el.style.touchAction = "inherit"
            }, true)
        }
        
        for (let i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            longPress(n[i], 1000, function(ev, _this) {
                if (ev.buttons === 1) {
                    _this.style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue"
                    _this.style.color = "#ddd"
                }
            });
            n[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                var _this = this
                for (let i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
                    if (n[i].style.backgroundColor === "dodgerblue" && _this.style.backgroundColor !== "dodgerblue") {

                        _this.style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue"
                        _this.style.color = "#ddd"
                        return;
                    } else if (n[i].style.backgroundColor === "dodgerblue" && _this.style.backgroundColor === "dodgerblue") {
                        _this.style.backgroundColor = "#333"
                        _this.style.color = "#999"
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (_this.style.backgroundColor === "dodgerblue") {
                    _this.style.backgroundColor = "#333"
                    _this.style.color = "#999"
                }
            });
        }
```

```css
         body {
            background: rgb(31, 31, 31);
        }

        .container {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .items {
            height: 200px;
            width: 45%;
            display: inline-flex;
            background: #333;
            border-radius: 20px;
            margin: 2px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="items"></div>
        <div class="items"></div>
        <div class="items"></div>
        <div class="items"></div>
        <div class="items"></div>
        <div class="items"></div>
        <div class="items"></div>
        <div class="items"></div>
        <div class="items"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding the event listener twice, removing that should fix it.

You can also just use a time difference to detect long press, instead of a setInterval.

Here's an working version of your code snippet:

```js
/* Detects long press, using time difference between pointer down and up events */
function longPress(el, timeout, callback) {
  let startTime = 0;
  el.addEventListener("pointerdown", function(ev) {
      startTime = new Date().getTime()
  })
  el.addEventListener("pointerup", function(ev) {
    const endTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (startTime && (endTime - startTime) > 300) {
        callback(ev, el)
      }
  }, true)
}

/* Toggles class for given element */
function toggleColor(el) {
  if (el.classList.contains("active")) {
    el.classList.remove("active")
    el.classList.add("disable")
  } else {
    el.classList.remove("disable")
    el.classList.add("active")
  }
}

function activeElement(el) {
toggleColor(el);
setTimeout(() => { toggleColor(el); }, 1000 );
}

/* Get list of item elements */
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.items');
  
const activate = (ev, _this) => { activeElement(_this) };

/* Iterate over elements, adding the pointer up/ down listeners */
items.forEach((item) => {
  longPress(item, 300, activate); 
});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(31, 31, 31);
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.items {
  height: 200px;
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-flex;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.active {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.disable {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't match what i need you make should to keep press on every element for a long time I want when there's one element is pressed and active the other elements can be actived by just click

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail? I'm not following

Comment: I've updated the sample to remove the class 1 second after applying it. Is that what you meant?

Comment: i don't know how can i explain it in more details it's something like the elements changed to be a check boxes when press on anyone of them then you can easily select or disselect others by click there was a problem with my js code i edited it so please try it in touch phone that's will be better